# Select box as button in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create button and after clicking it I select value `export` and run `<button type="submit" class="button" title="Run" name="index" value="0">Run</button>`?

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="actions">
        <label>Action: <select name="action">

        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="export">Export</option>

    </select></label><input class="select-across" name="select_across" type="hidden" value="0" />

    <button type="submit" class="button" title="Run" name="index" value="0">Run</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("select").on("change", function() { if ($(this).val() == "export") $("button").click(); });`

Comment: +1 MelanciaUK, proper way to do this :)

Comment: -1 for posting answers in comments. :P

Comment: OK, I'll post as an answer then. :D

Comment: +1 for first posting the answer in the comment, showing how easy it is, and +1 for **then** posting the real answer, showing that you're not a reputation stealer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var newButton = $("<button />").attr({
        id: "newButton",
        name: "newButton"        
    })
    .text("New Button")
    .on("click", function() {
        $("select[name=action]").val("export").change();
    })
    .appendTo("body");

    $("select[name=action]").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "export") {
            $("button[name=index]").click();
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/758odk00/1/)

**Note:** I've just added the missing part that actually creates a new button.

Answer (score 0):

If i have interpretted your question correctly, you wish to **create** a new button that, when clicked:

1> changes the value of the select box to export

2> clicks the submit button:

```
<button id="newbutton">Do stuff</button>

<div class="actions">
        <label>Action: <select name="action">

        <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
        <option value="export">Export</option>

    </select></label><input class="select-across" name="select_across" type="hidden" value="0" />

    <button type="submit" class="button" title="Run" name="index" value="0">Run</button>
</div>

//your javascript:
$(function () {
    $("#newbutton").click( function() { 
         $("select[name=action]").val("export");
         $("button[name=index]").trigger("click"); 
    });
});
```